# access plist value returning null

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to access a NSNumber Plist entry thats in my NSUserDefaults plist. It is set to 0 initially but when I try to access it to check this value its coming back as null and imi just not sure why.

this is the code I am using

```
 // setup user defaults ready for use
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // gets the current data base version stored in default prefs plist
    NSNumber *currentDataVersion = [prefs objectForKey: @"CurrentDBV"];

    // Check Current DataVersion
    NSLog(@"current dbv = %@", currentDataVersion); // logs (NULL)
```

I am using this code in applicationDidBecomeActive of my app delegate.

Comment: I didnt think you had to set NSUserDefaults..

Comment: make sure the key "CurrentDBV" is right in your setter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have your options in **NSUserDefault** :

```
 – setFloat:forKey:
 – setInteger:forKey:
 – setDouble:forKey:
```

Now retrieve it:

```
 – floatForKey:
 – integerForKey:
 – doubleForKey:
```

For example like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:3.15 forKey:@"key"];
float value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"key"];
NSLog(@"value: %.0f", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [prefs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.00] forKey: @"CurrentDBV"];

NSLog(@"current dbv = %f", [currentDataVersion floatValue]); // logs (NULL)

Comment: yup, that works setting it.. but I would only want this to happen the first time.. so i guess i could check for null.. if its null assign it a temp value untill i give it the propper currentDBV..

Comment: with int - you can't add in decimals -so it's v1 / v2 /v3 >  better off using doubles. floats can be a head ache.

Comment: I think my new head ach is comming form me trying to put your setObject into an if statment.. I want to prevent this from being set to 3 every time the app opens and only happen if durrentDBV is null... how could I do that with out breaking things.

Comment: regarding the dbversion it will only ever be a 8 digit number.. no decimal points which is why i was going with an integer.